# yaml.dump() is printing raw string

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

If I run the following code:

```
import yaml
d = {'data': 'a\n b'}
print(yaml.dump(d))
```

This prints:

```
data: "a\n b"
```

But I want it to print

```
data: 'a
 b'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I believe that your desired output is equivalent to `data: "a b"`; the newline gets turned into a space, so this isn't actually a valid encoding of your input data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "raw string" in YAML, that is something from Python, and
it doesn't appear in any part of your code or output. YAML
has scalars, some of which are typically loaded as strings within Python. If YAML scalars
are unquoted then can be interpreted (as boolean, datetime, float, etc). If they are quoted or
are block style scalars then the interpretation/transformation of such scalar follows
different rules.

If you are loading YAML and there is a newline in a single quoted scalar in YAML and
the line following that newline is not empty, that newline, *and its surrounding white
space*, is converted to a single space.

So if you load your expected output (I am using `ruamel.yaml` here as it is supports YAML 1.2, whereas
PyYAML only supports a subset of YAML 1.1, outdated since 2009):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
data: 'a
 b'
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.width = 6
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'data': 'a b'}
```

If you don't exactly know what you are doing when generating YAML, start with loading
the expected output. Manipulating strings in the data you want to dump almost never
has the desired effect as YAML has its own representation rules for scalars, which are
different from escaping in Python strings.

As far as I know you cannot get the output you want using `ruamel.yaml` without post processing
the output of the dump (and neither can PyYAML), as there is no way to insert the spurious space before
the letter `b` in any other way. You can reduce the line width to force the newline (if you have no other
longer lines, i.e. when not using some more realistic data).

PyYAML's `dump()` function
never prints anything: it either streams to the second parameter, or it buffers that stream and returns
it as a string (which can be handed to `print`) .
PyYAML allows you to do `print(yaml.dump(d))`. That is even in the documentation but
it is bad practise. It is much more efficient (in time and memory usage) to use `yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout))`,
and apart from that it doesn't change the output by adding an extra newline.